# Feedback vibration in swift like apple breathe

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, feedback, vibration

I'm trying to reproduce apple watch's breathe on the iPhone but i'm not able to reproduce the feedback vibration that the watch gives to the user while breathing. I tried with this:

```
for _ in 1...5 {
    AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID)
    AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
    sleep(1)
}
```

But the vibration is too heavy and (because of the for cycle) is not as fluid as apple watch one.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply use Haptics using Taptic engine in order to have a lighter feedback.

**Swift 3**

```
WKInterfaceDevice.current.playHaptic(.success)
```

**Objective-C**

```
[[WKInterfaceDevice currentDevice] playHaptic:WKHapticType.Success];
```

For more information and possible enum values visit [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkinterfacedevice).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, really. But if i got it right, you can only use WKInterfaceDevice on the AppleWatch. I wanna reproduce that feedback on the iPhone without using the watch. Otherwise, i'm now using AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1520)

Comment: The nearest thing to your question is using Taptic Engine in iPhone 7 (made similar to Apple Watch) This link includes a great tutorial to make this possible: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-generate-haptic-feedback-with-uifeedbackgenerator - This will be very similar to Apple Watch haptics but not exactly like them. They have lighter feedback.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5:**

```
WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(.success)
```